# How to store Matillion job variable value in Snowflake table

Tags: variables, iterator, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, matillion

I have an Orchestration job running in which I am using an iterator component. I have created a job variable which is reading filename for the iterator.
Is their any way to store the variable value (i.e. filename) in a Snowflake table?

Thank you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RnvNt.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zysfz.png)

Answer (score 1):

Start with a fixed flow component in a transformation Job.  Add a column of type varchar and name the variable: Var1_Value

Add a value to the fixed flow: ${VAR1} (if your job variable is named 'VAR1')
Then output the fixed flow to a rewrite table component.

since you are using an orchestration job, you can pass the variable into the transformation job to write it out.

That will store the value of the variable into a Snowflake table.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you, Peter. I ended up using a simple SQL Script with the same orchestration job and it worked for me.